Iterative update data.table entries in R using data.table syntax/features
I want to use data.table for its memory/speed features (and at this point I much prefer its syntax to the plyr syntax). I have a use case where I want to iteratively update some values with a scalar multiplier using shift for lagging the values by year, but the only way I can think to do this uses lapply which won't work how I want since that applies the function to the entire list at once, not updating for each element in the list.
A MWE for some context:
library(data.table)
set.seed(355)
dt <- data.table(year = c(2020:2022), mean = runif(3, .25,.75), lower = runif(3, 0, .25), upper = runif(3, .75, 1))
dt[year > 2020, `:=`(mean = NA, lower = NA, upper = NA)]
gr <- 1.04
dt

> dt
    year      mean      lower    upper
   <int>     <num>      <num>    <num>
1:  2020 0.3325526 0.04151428 0.848173
2:  2021        NA         NA       NA
3:  2022        NA         NA       NA

Say I want to update the mean, lower, and upper by the given growth rate, but do it in a way that it replaces the 2021 value with the 2020 value multiplied by the growth rate. I can do this as below with lapply and shift(.SD) but that applies it to the whole list of values as they are input, which is
> dt$mean
[1] 0.3325526        NA        NA

and so it generates a new 2021 value but replaces the 2020 with NA and doesn't update 2022 since NA*1.04 returns NA, like so:
dt[, c("mean", "lower", "upper") := lapply(.SD, function(x){shift(x)*gr}), .SDcols = c("mean", "lower", "upper")]

> dt
    year      mean      lower     upper
   <int>     <num>      <num>     <num>
1:  2020        NA         NA        NA
2:  2021 0.3458548 0.04317485 0.8820999
3:  2022        NA         NA        NA

I can get around this with a for loop iterating over the year variable, but that is obviously slow and doesn't leverage the efficiency of data.table. Is there a way to do this within the data.table syntax and preserving the efficiency gains you get?

Just to confirm, is your goal to have 2020 unchanged and each year after that be 1.04 times the prior row?

In dplyr, I'd use dt |> mutate(across(mean:upper, ~.x * 1.04 ^ (row_number() - 1))). In this use case, converting your problem to a vectorized approach will support vastly more efficiency gains than your choice of data.table/dplyr (or collapse, duckdb, polars, etc. to name some other highly performant packages).

With data.table:
library(data.table)
set.seed(355)
dt <- data.table(year = c(2020:2022), mean = runif(3, .25,.75), lower = runif(3, 0, .25), upper = runif(3, .75, 1))
dt[year > 2020, `:=`(mean = NA, lower = NA, upper = NA)]
gr <- 1.04
dt
#>     year      mean      lower    upper
#>    <int>     <num>      <num>    <num>
#> 1:  2020 0.3325526 0.04151428 0.848173
#> 2:  2021        NA         NA       NA
#> 3:  2022        NA         NA       NA


cols = c("mean", "lower", "upper")
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, \(a) a[1]*gr^(.I - 1)), .SDcols=cols]

dt
#>     year      mean      lower     upper
#>    <int>     <num>      <num>     <num>
#> 1:  2020 0.3325526 0.04151428 0.8481730
#> 2:  2021 0.3458548 0.04317485 0.8820999
#> 3:  2022 0.3596889 0.04490185 0.9173839

Created on 2024-10-15 with reprex v2.1.1

This worked perfectly, thank you. The \a a[1]*gr^(.I-1) syntax is new to me, is there somewhere I can read up on it? I get the .I -1 part but is the \a some sort of anonymous function?

\(a) marks an anonymous function. It's equivalent to function(a). It's base R syntax, not specific to data.table. I believe the shorthand was added in R 4.1.

Ah okay. How does the a[1] work then? That looks like referencing the first value of a vector, is it referencing the first (and only) argument to the anonymous function then?

a represents column of dt (one of three columns we feed to lapply). a[1] is the first value of that column. We need that first value, because we multiply it by the growth rate gr. For example, for column mean, the initial vector that goes into the anonymous function is c(0.3325526, NA, NA). The final value that comes out is mean[1]*gr^(0:2). lapply runs the anonymous function on each of the three columns we feed to it.
